# PostInstall script disappearing when building package

Tags: package, bug, postinstall

After specifying a `PostInstallScript` on a package, then building it, the field disappears while it's processing:

[image: Missing PostInstallScript]

It seems that it's not functionally an issue, as when the package is built it's still there - but it's a bit disconcerting to say the least. Is there any specific step I need to take to ensure that it still shows up while building?